# How to implement PayEx Payment Gateway in ASP.NET API?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, api, payment-gateway, payment

I have a api for mobile application, and i want to implement PayEx Payment gateway in my api.
User will do payment through mobile and all process will handle on api, user will only get success and error of payement on mobile side.
so is there any help for PayEx Payment gateway for asp.net MVC 5

here is c# implemenatation
https://developer.payex.com/xwiki/wiki/developer/view/Sandbox/payex-checkout-v1/

Comment: What have you tried thus far ? Have you checked their website for how to use their API ?

Comment: @stom yes, but did't get any proper solution for asp.net api, dnt know how to start actually, so help me out

Comment: https://developer.payex.com/xwiki/wiki/developer/view/Sandbox/payex-checkout-v1/

Comment: Ok good , As mentioned in their doc, we need to pass `Json` data to their api. So Create a ViewModel class with required property of payex. And Post Json data to their API. I have edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Two Solutions:**

1. Check their API to understand required data you as a client should post to their API.

   - Create a ViewModel class with required property of payex
   - Post the required Data from Populated ViewModel to their API using [Http Client](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/webapi/consume-web-api-post-method-in-aspnet-mvc)
   - Setup a Callback ActionMethod in your ASP.NET API , So that they can post Payment Status details to your API.
2. Contact their technical team to get ASP.NET Support to call their API.

Hope this helps.